# Unable to connect to rubygems.org from a linux server. Handshake_failure

Tags: ruby, plugins, rubygems, logstash, sslhandshakeexception

I was trying to install logstash plugins in a Linux server in cloud(Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09). and got the error that the server is not able to download data from https://rubygems.org. Handshake_failure

*Command used to install plugin*: **sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-environment**

*Error log*: **Validating logstash-filter-environment
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org - Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR: Installation aborted, verification failed for logstash-filter-environment**

Tried to access this website from this server with this command: **w3m https://rubygems.org**

*Error log*: **Bad cert ident from rubygems.org: dNSName=j.sni.global.fastly.net**

I can successfully wget https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz from the server and it got downloaded successfully.

**Got this issue with Ruby 2.0, so upgraded version to Ruby 3.0 and still the same error.**

Comment: This looks like a network-level issue, possibly a firewall-type device that's mangling TLS certificates. The certificate for `rubygems.org` belongs to that domain, this `fastly.net` thing is something else, a generic CDN cert you shouldn't be seeing. Have you tried on a different network? Or with a different computer?

Comment: This server is on AWS cloud. This issue appeared on all the servers at once in our org. Previously it used it work, i had installed these plugins back in December 2020 and it worked.

Comment: Try a different server. More importantly, try and image that's *less than five years old* as TLS might be the issue here. Many sites have moved to TLS > 1.1 which a 2016 image might not support.